# How to use RemoteWebDriver + WebDriverBackedSelenium to connect to current grid (Not Grid2)

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

If I can make use of `RemoteWebDriver` + `WebDriverBackedSelenium` and then connect to the existing selenium grid (Not Grid 2 that is recently released)

I need this to be able to provide backward compatibility in our framework, so that our users can make use of Selenium2 libraries and still work against the grid.

Following is how I am trying to get this done:

```
URL remoteAddress = new URL("http://mymachine:4444/");
//have tried using the below commented out lines as well, but in all cases I face errors.
//URL remoteAddress = new URL("http://mymachine:4444/grid/register");
//URL remoteAddress = new URL("http://mymachine:4444/wd/hub");

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress, DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.google.com");
```

I have a Grid running on "mymachine" in port "4444" and it does have **Firefox Remote Controls** hooked on to it.

The moment the statement

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress, DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```

gets executed I get all sorts of errors.

Just wanted to know if Selenium2 does indeed provide backward compatibility to work with Grid 1, by making use of WebDriverBackedSelenium.

I am using Selenium 2.03b version.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same Selenium 2.03b version for grid too. You can manually update the jar in `/vendor` folder.

Comment: AJ : Can you please help elaborate your answer ? I didnt quite get you